# How do I turn off undercurls in Vim-GUIs?

Tags: gvim, macvim

How do I globally turn off undercurls in Vim-GUIs (GVim & MacVim)?

Comment: You mean spell-checking?

Comment: You can use the command :setlocal spell! to toggle its state from on to off. If you wish to toggle it on later, :setlocal spell! spelllang=<lang> or add to your .vimrc

Comment: I see the confusion. Even the :set form of the command does not appear global, and acts local to the active buffer.

Comment: No, I don't mean spell checking. Some plugins (for example autozimus LanguageClient-neovim) mark errors this way. I already have my errors in the sign gutter and don't need additional noise in my code. So I thought there might be a way to turn undercurls off regardless of where they originate.

Comment: You were right. It was the spell checker. And it wasn't LanguageClient-neovim, that used its settings, but ALE.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution myself. Enter `:hi SpellBad`, `:hi SpellCap`, `:hi SpellRare` and `:hi SpellLocal` in normal mode. It will output the display settings of your spell checker. Note the output in a list. Remove all parameters with the value `undercurl`. Add this to your `.vimrc`, changed according to your own settings.

```
autocmd ColorScheme * hi clear SpellBad
    \| hi SpellBad term=reverse ctermbg=12 guisp=Firebrick2
    \| hi SpellCap term=reverse ctermbg=9 guisp=Blue
    \| hi SpellRare term=reverse ctermbg=13 guisp=Magenta
    \| hi SpellLocal term=underline ctermbg=11 guisp=DarkCyan
```

The important part is, that no parameter with the value `undercurl` is present.